# Very slow wifi on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I dual boot Ubuntu 20.04LTS with Windows 10. In Windows 10, network speed is always maximum. However, in Ubuntu, the network is very unstable. The speed falls randomly and a google search might take 10 seconds to load. My network driver is `RTL8821CE 802.11ac`

wireless-info output: https://termbin.com/bkt3

I saw all questions related to this topic on AskUbuntu, and none of them yielded a satisfying result. If you are going to point out https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce, don't waste your time, it only made wifi slower because it's outdated (the dev abandonned it in 2019)

There's this driver installed, but Idk if the problem comes from it.
[image]

I'd be pleased if anyone can assist me into this frustrating problem.

There is a point that may be useful, when I first installed Ubuntu, wifi was very good. And then after some months, I don't remember when exactly, the speed started to fall down, maybe I installed a faulty update or sth? Maybe I should revert wireless network settings to their initial state just after install ?

---

### ADDITIONAL INFO

```
$ lsmod | grep 8821
rtw88_8821ce           16384  0
rtw88_8821c            94208  1 rtw88_8821ce
rtw88_pci              32768  1 rtw88_8821ce
rtw88_core            253952  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_8821c
```

```
$ sudo dkms status
rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1, 5.13.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1, 5.15.0-41-generic, x86_64: built
```

After executing `sudo apt install --reinstall rtl8821ce-dkms`

```
$ lsmod | grep 8821
rtl8821ce            2031616  0
cfg80211              954368  1 rtl8821ce
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the results of the terminal commands: `lsmod | grep 8821` and `sudo dkms status`

Comment: @chili555 here you go

Comment: It appears that the dkms version was merely built but not installed. Please try: `sudo apt install --reinstall rtl8821ce-dkms` If it fails and refers you to a make.log, please edit your question to show the make.log. If it succeeds, reboot and show us again: `lsmod | grep 8821`

Comment: @chili555 see my edit. For now the speed seems fine, does the output show it is fixed ?

Comment: It sure seems like it. Please test for a day or so. I shall convert this to an answer.

Comment: Okay, Ill post an update tomorrow. Thanks for taking the time to help me

Comment: @chili555 sorry for the delay, it seems fixed. You can post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the correct driver was, in the dkms process, built, but not properly installed. With a working internet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall rtl8821ce-dkms
```

Reboot. You should be all set.